# Tensorflow audio features extraction process won't run

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, feature-extraction, tf.keras

I am trying to build my own audio TF dataset using some documentation from [devicehive](https://github.com/devicehive/devicehive-audio-analysis) project. I have two PC machines, the same exact project works on one, but it doesn't work on the other! It  gives a warning about TF then says "Using TensorFlow backend.", as shown below.

Any idea about what would be the reason behind this issue?

```
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/ic6/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

Using TensorFlow backend.
[Finished in 2.3s]
```

Comment: I just making here an assumption, therefore I post this as a comment. Are you sure both of your computer have the same tf version installed. Google threw their old library out of the window and made a lot of changes in every new tensorflow version. Therefore the code will run on one pc if an older tensorflow version has been installed, while this has not be true for a system that has been set up recently.

Comment: @Harald Yes, both of them have the same tf version installed. v. 1.14

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
It turned out that I missed placing "/" the slash at the end of my wav folder path!
That's all!